# Is it possible to convert this to method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Lambdas should be replaced with method references (java:S1612)

Solarlint says to convert x->x.stream here to method reference but I am having trouble determining how to do this to remove warning

```
List<String> rtn = Stream.of(listA,listB,listC).flatMap(x->x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible to do this or solarlint detection bug?

Comment: yes List::stream

Comment: Try `Collection::stream`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
List<String> rtn = Stream.of(listA, listB, listC).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: sorry. Mistakes were made

Comment: I though for a moment that x was some other variable. nvm

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that `java.util.Collection`? And which JDK?

Comment: @Davide yup it is

Comment: the stream api and labda support was introduced in JDK 1.8+

Comment: I'm asking because when I test that code I have an error because `Collection.stream()` is not static. So, I'm not sure how that can work

Comment: Collection::stream is the same as (list) -> list.stream()
This has nothing to do with static methods. It is a lambda.
@Davide Have a look at this tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html
And please update your java version to at least 1.8. Java got so much better

Comment: I removed the unnecessary flatmap call. Don't know how that ended up in there

Comment: Right, sorry, there was a typo in my test code. I thought `stream` need to have a parameter. Thanks